# Rolify Gem Strict Mode/Scoped Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

I have a simple Rails 4 app with only two empty models, User and Job. And I'm using the Rolify gem, in strict mode, to give the Users roles.

i.e (Strict Mode per the [documentation](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#strict-mode))

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    rolify strict: true
end
```

Essentially I want Users with the role *engineer* to be able to have certain permissions for the Job class, but not necessarily permissions for a specific Job.

So I give user1 the role of *engineer* for the Job class and for an instance of the Job class. While user2 only gets the role of *engineer* for the Job class. Just like the documentation.

```
job = Job.create() # Job class instance

user1.add_role(:engineer, Job) # Job class
user1.add_role(:engineer, job) # Job class instance

user2.add_role(:engineer, Job) # Job class
```

Which works fine and I can say things like;

```
user1.has_role? :engineer, Job #=> true
user1.has_role? :engineer, job #=> true

user2.has_role? :engineer, Job #=> true
user2.has_role? :engineer, job #=> false This is the result I expect.
```

But when I try to make a class level rolify call

(i.e Class Level per the [documentation](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#class-level))

```
User.with_role(:engineer, job)
# => [ list of User instances that have a scoped role of "engineer" to a job instance ]
```

It returns **both** user1 and user2. When I only expected user1 because it was specifically tied to that instance. Does strict mode not work that way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Same here. Seems a legitimate bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug, so I filed an issue here: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/362

To proceed with your life, you may do a `has_role?` double check for each of the users returned.

`User.with_role(:engineer, job).select{|user| user.has_role?(:engineer, job)}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that will work for now. I'll keep an eye on the github issue page. And I guess this can be the accepted answer until the alleged bug is addressed. Thanks again.